# setroubleshootd showing ~100% CPU utilization

Tags: centos

One of my centos7 machines shows `setroubleshootd` running at between 70-100% CPU utilization.

I tried to *temporarily* disable SELinux with `setenforce 0`, just so I could use `sealert` to read the audit.log file, but doing so does not stop the runaway process.   I've also tried killing the `setroubleshootd` process to no avail.

Are there any other tricks to temporarily stop settroubleshootd from running so that I can analyze audit.log and determine what the underlying issue is?